# Facebook signed request get UID PHP

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

```
require_once 'library/facebook/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId'  => 'appid',
'secret' => 'secret',
));

$signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
```

How to get UID after the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to include facebook api for this. Just to this,

```
$data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
echo $data["user_id"];
```

This is a complete list of other info in `$data` array.

```
{
  "algorithm": "HMAC-SHA256",
  "expires": 1317243600,
  "issued_at": 1317239909,
  "oauth_token": "<token>",
  "page": {
    "id": "<id>",
    "liked": false,
    "admin": true
  },
  "user": {
    "country": "in",
    "locale": "en_GB",
    "age": {
      "min": 21
    }
  },
  "user_id": "<user-id>"
}
```

Comment: thanks, quick question, is user_id available to PHP page if application has not been granted any permissions, or any other way to get user_id without requesting permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using php sdk,

You can simply say

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

PHP sdk will read the uid from signed_request.

or

you can take directly from signed request by this

```
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$user = isset($signed_request['user_id']) ? $signed_request['user_id'] : '';
```

Comment: thanks, can this user_id be available without requesting for permissions first, any work around, because I can see it's not available at first.

Comment: You don't get user_id without user authorizing the app.