# Create FB app to Check 'Like' for fb page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to create an integration with my site and FB and I'm quite confused by the FB documentation (it is a long flow of words, not dev friendly on my point of view ) and authorization token.

My 'app' should **only check if the user 'liked' my fb page** and on the base of this display some content on my site.

I'm confused about the following point:

- What it is the best way to do it ( *PHP SDK* or *JS SDK* ) ?
- What kind of app should I create ( *Website with Facebook Login* ? , *Page Tab* ? )
- is it possible to accomplish the task without an *authorization token* or ask the user to authorize the app ?

**What I have done so far**:

I'm using 2 approach:

1. Graph API( not sure about the correct name )

   - works but ask to the user permission for my app
2. PHP SDK

   - doesn't work: I think it requires log in
   - I would prefer to use this method as it is more clean ( no redirect )

**1. Graph API**

```
<?php
$app_id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$app_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$my_url = 'http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.net/testfb.php';

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

// auth user
if (empty($code)) {
    $dialog_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id='
        . $app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url);
    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}

// get user access_token
$token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='
    . $app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url)
    . '&client_secret=' . $app_secret
    . '&code=' . $code;

// response is of the format "access_token=AAAC..."
$access_token = substr(file_get_contents($token_url), 13);

$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
    . 'fql?q=SELECT+uid+FROM+page_fan+WHERE+page_id=351144741645225+AND+uid=me()'
    . '&access_token=' . $access_token;

$fql_query_obj = json_decode(file_get_contents($fql_query_url), true);

$data = array();
echo 'User Liked ?';

// display results of fql query
if (isset($fql_query_obj['data'])) {
    $data = $fql_query_obj['data'];
}
if (isset($data[0])) {
    echo 'YES';
} else {
    echo 'NO';
}
```

**2. PHP SDK**

```
<?php

require './lib/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'cookie' => 'true'
));
//$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
//$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
var_dump($user);
//if ($user) {
    try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

        $isFan = $facebook->api(array(
            "method" => "fql.query",
            "query" => "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = 'yyyyyyyyyy' AND uid = me()"
        ));
        var_dump($isFan);

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
    }
//} else {
//    echo 'no logged in';
//}
```

Answer (score 0):

i did this recently. Idea is a follows:

1. When user first loads your app, it happens through POST request. At that time, Facebook posts a field called "signed_request".
2. You need to decode it and there you can get page.liked object - which tells you if user liked the page or not (thanks to [Facebook signed request get UID PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893557/facebook-signed-request-get-uid-php)):

> $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
>
> list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
>
> $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
>
> echo $data["page.liked"];

that seems to be it - no need in facebook SDK or any complex code.